# Fastest way to index large sorted hash file

Tags: bash, grep

I am building a file-based index for the sorted [haveibeenpwned](https://haveibeenpwned.com/Passwords) passwords text file and it got me wondering what's the fastest way to do this?

I figured a good way to build a quickly grep-able index would be split the sorted file into 256 files named with the first two hex digits (i.e. FF.txt, FE.txt, etc).  I found ripgrep `rg` to be about 5 times faster than grep on my computer.  So I tried something like this:

```
for i in {255..0} 
do
    start=$(date +%s)
    hex="$(printf  '%02x' $i  | tr [:lower:] [:upper:])"
    rg "^$hex" pwned-passwords-ntlm-ordered-by-hash-v4.txt > ntlm/$hex-ntlm.txt
    echo 0x$hex completed in $(($(date +%s) - $start)) seconds
done
```

This is the fastest solution I could come up with.  ripgrep is able to create each file in 25 seconds.  So I'm looking at about 100 minutes to create this index.  When I split the job in half, and run them in parallel, each pair of files is created in 80 seconds.   So it seems best to just let ripgrep work its magic and work in series.

Obviously, I won't be indexing this list too often, but it's just fun to think about.  Any thoughts on a faster way (aside from using a database) to index this file?

Comment: If you want speed, don't use external commands, or forks. No `$(...)`, no pipes, no `tr`, no `rg`.

Comment: Thanks @kamil-cuk for the formatting help!

Comment: For example: `printf -v hex '%02X' "$i"` is a much faster way of doing `hex="$(printf  '%02x' $i  | tr [:lower:] [:upper:])"`.

Comment: And `printf -v start '%(%s)T' -1` is a much faster alternative to `start=$(date +%s)`

Comment: Of course, you don't want to use `date +%s` again later in your `echo` either.

Comment: ...after all those changes, your biggest cost will be running all the copies of `rg`. Not knowing what that is, it's hard to say how to optimize it. In general, if you *can* run a tool just once instead of once-per-loop-entry, you should always do that (single invocation processing all your data, vs one-invocation-per-datum).

Comment: The file has 11GB, so the cost of `date +%s` is negligible. The operation `rg "^$hex"` is the only significantly consuming time. `rg` works the same as `grep` and according to [their github readme](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) runs faster then `grep`.

Comment: Ahh. In that case, I'd start by optimizing the file -- pre-sort it and then you can use `seek()`-based grep tools that do a bisection to run in logarithmic time rather than O(n). Or, if it's *already* sorted, stop using tools that try to work with unsorted inputs and switch to tools optimized for sorted-inputs-only.

Comment: @pixelrebel Basically you want to do a binary search on a sorted file. Short google gave me [sgrep](http://sgrep.sourceforge.net/) and [this unix.stackexchange thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247508/binary-search-in-a-sorted-text-file). There is no need to "hash" the file in any way - it's already sorted, splitting it into smaller parts is like, well, not really the optimal way about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ripgrep`, like any other tool that's able to work with unsorted input files at all, is the wrong tool for this job. When you're trying to grep sorted inputs, you want something that can bisect your input file to find a position in logarithmic time. For big enough inputs, even a slow O(log n) implementation will be faster than a highly optimized O(n) one.

[`pts-line-bisect`](https://github.com/pts/pts-line-bisect) is one such tool, though of course you're also welcome to write your own. You'll need to write it in a language with full access to the `seek()` syscall, which is not exposed in bash.

Comment: pts_lbsearch is exactly what I'm looking for to solve the larger problem.  No index is needed at all!  `pts_lbsearch -p hashes.sorted $myhash` finds the result (and more importantly, the negative result) instantly!  This answer sent me down the binary search rabbit-hole to learn more how it works on this application.  I remember learning about binary search way back in college, but I've never practically applied it to a sorted text file.  Amazing.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are reading through the file 256 times, doing a full file scan every time.  Consider an approach that reads the file once, writing each line into an open file descriptor.  I'm thinking python would be an easy choice of implementation (if that's your thing).  You could optimize by keeping the file open until you hit a new hex code at the beginning of the line.  If you want to be even more clever, there is no need to go through the sorted file line by line.  Based on Charles Duffy's hint, you could create a heuristic for sampling the file (using `seek()`) to get to the next hex value.  Once the program has found the byte offset of the next hex value, the block of bytes can be written to the new file.  However, since this is tagged as 'bash' let's keep the solution set in that domain:

```
while 
  read line 
do
  hex=${line:0:2}
  echo $line >> ntlm/$hex-ntlm.txt
done < pwned-passwords-ntlm-ordered-by-hash-v4.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This is the mindset I needed to get into to solve this problem.    Unfortunately, the above solution is actually slower than the brute-force ripgrep because it is single-threaded.  However, it turns out a binary search is the perfect application for this problem, so I gave the check to Mr. Duffy.  Thanks again for the lesson!

Comment: That's perfectly correct - the important insight was the binary search.  Also, doing the operation in parallel is key since there is file I/O involved.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Python3 script that solves fast binary-search lookups in the hash file without having to create an index. It doesn't directly address your question (indexing) but probably solves the underlying problem that you wanted to solve with an index - to quickly look up individual hashes. This script checks hundreds of passwords in seconds.

```
import argparse
import hashlib

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Searches passwords in https://haveibeenpwned.com/Passwords database.')
parser.add_argument('passwords', metavar='TEST', type=str, help='text file with passwords to test, one per line, utf-8')
parser.add_argument('database', metavar='DATABASE', type=str, help='the downloaded text file with sha-1:count')
args = parser.parse_args()

def search(f: object, pattern: str) -> str:

    def search(left, right: int) -> str:
        if left >= right:
            return None

        middle = (left + right) // 2
        if middle == 0:
            f.seek(0, 0)
            test = f.readline()
        else:
            f.seek(middle - 1, 0)
            _ = f.readline()
            test = f.readline()

        if test.upper().startswith(pattern):
            return test
        elif left == middle:
             return None
        elif pattern < test:
            return search(left, middle)
        else:
            return search(middle, right)

    f.seek(0, 2)
    return search(0, f.tell())

fsource = open(args.passwords)
fdatabase = open(args.database)
source_lines = fsource.readlines()
for l in source_lines:
    line = l.strip()
    hash_object = hashlib.sha1(line.encode("utf-8"))
    pattern = hash_object.hexdigest().upper()
    print("%s:%s" % (line, str(search(fdatabase, pattern)).strip()))
fsource.close()
fdatabase.close()
```